# require function does not work. ( Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@/images/01.jpg' )

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm studying vue3 js and I don't know why I get this Bug.Please help me.

this is the json data sample:

```
{
  "full": "/static/images/fulls/01.jpg",
  "pathUrl": "/static/images/thumbs/01.jpg",
}
```

the function is:

```
created: function() {
...

arr.forEach(imgItor => {
  let newObj = { id: 0, full: '', pathUrl: '', descript: 'Lorem ipsum'};
  newObj.id = uid++;
  newObj.full = require(`@${imgItor.full.replace('/static', '/assets')}`);
  newObj.pathUrl = require(`@${imgItor.pathUrl.replace('/static', '/assets')}`);

...
}
```

the chrome console op is

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/images/fulls/01.jpg'
```

What am I doing wrong with the `require` usage?

When I use the code below, it works:

```
        newObj.full = require(`@/assets/images/fulls/0${uid}.jpg`);
        newObj.pathUrl = require(`@/assets/images/thumbs/0${uid}.jpg`);
```

I want to understand the `require` function and how to use it to dynamically load a image from json data.

Comment: Do you use Webpack or Vite? Do you need a dynamic image? If you do, did you searched on how to achieve such thing before posting? Otherwise, you could try without any `require` or fancy thing.

Comment: i was created by vue cli 'vue create'. If so, am I using webpack? dynamic image is not!  It's a just image file. i just want to know how to load a image from json data.

Comment: Fastest way to know: check your code to see the configuration file. Also, [this is](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application) the correct way of creating a VueJS app with the latest and greatest CLI.

Comment: for example) let path = '@/assets/01.jpg'; 
What is the difference between 'require(path)' and 'require('@/assets/01.jpg') ?

Comment: One is a path, the other is a hardcoded string. Please consider all the things that I wrote in my previous comment so that we can move forward.